# Strange characters appearing on posts wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problems with a wordpress install.

I've installed many wordress website, and never had this problem.

I though it was because I was copying and pasting from another application, but it's happening a post's that I am purely typing from scratch.

The type characters appearing are... **â€“ â€œ â€™ â€**

I don't know what to do? I'm running the latest Wordpresss 3.3.1

My Config is completely standard with...

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Any help or advice would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure ur function is actually working by checking the front end html. You should have a piece of meta that looks similar to this:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: Hi Matt, this seem to fix the problem, but I was using the html5 boiler plate for my theme which has <meta charset="utf-8"> for the character encoding. I don't understand why that doesn't seem to work but the html4 version does. Hmmmm

Comment: i develop all my latest sites on a stripped version of the Boilerplate  markup as there's still bugs like this :-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @Matt, it fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the files in your wordpress theme and wordpress home directory are right set as utf8 when they are saved. Secondly, check your header.php file for the html headers where the encoding is declared, it may not be utf8.

My bet is that it is something from the database. Despite your wordpress confing say everything is right, your database may not support special chars and this is why it happens. I had the same problem but with other cms. If you can export all your posts and data, reinstall wordpress from scratch and import it.

Comment: thanks, checked that out and I have <meta charset="utf-8"> in the header PHP, however when I add the code @Matt posted, the characters disappear. So the html5 declaration is not working... weird?